# Efficient way to run headless JavaScript in Android

Tags: javascript, android, webview, cross-platform

I want to write some cross-platform business-logic code in JS and run it on Web, Android and iOS. 
On the Web I just use the browser's JavaScript and on iOS, **since this component has no UI**, utilize [JavsScriptCore](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/javascriptcore) (this framework allows execution of JavaScript without UI and DOM).

However, it seems that Android doesn't have the equivalent of JavaScriptCore. I have seen solutions such as [LiquidCore](https://github.com/LiquidPlayer/LiquidCore) that bring a complete NodeJS env to Android, but I'm looking for a solution that will not add more than ~1-2 MB to the APK (and I don't need the power of NodeJS).

- Is there a lower-level JavaScript runner API in Android that I missed? In theory it should be possible to directly utilize V8, but it's not exposed.
- Does it make sense to use a hidden (but always-alive) WebView for that purpose? How heavy is it on memory and CPU when not using any UI?
- Should I go with Rhino instead? Rhino is a mature but relatively lightweight JS interpreter, implemented in Java (the runtime is around 1MB).

By "efficient" here I mean a solution that is easy on memory, CPU and app footprint.

Comment: "Is there a lower-level JavaScript runner API in Android that I missed?" -- no, sorry. "How heavy is it on memory and CPU when not using any UI?" -- last I knew, that would depend a lot on whether you were using `WebView` anywhere else. You could look at duktape as an alternative.